# Continuity of sum/product using characteristic property of product topology

Tags: general-topology, universal-property, product-space

I'm self studying Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, and I'm familiarising myself to the characteristic/universal property view of topology. 
One of the exercises in chapter 3 goes as follows:

> Suppose $\,f_1,\,f_2:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous
>    functions. Let 
>   $$(f_1+f_2)(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x),$$ 
>   $$(f_1\cdot f_2)(x) = f_1(x)\cdot f_2(x)$$
>
> Use the characteristic property of the product topology to show that the pontwise sums and products of continuous
>   functions are continuous.

Now, I'm still new to this way of dealing with things, so my attempt, which I think is a bit convoluted, was as follows:

The characteristic property states that if $\prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ has the product topology and Y is a topological space, a map $\,f:Y\rightarrow\prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha$ is continuous if and only if each of its component functions $f_i = \pi_\alpha \circ f$ are continuous, where $\pi_\alpha$ is the canonical projection.

The book just showed that if $\,f_1$ and $\,f_2$ are continuous, the product map $\,f_1\times f_2$ is continuous.

We build a commutative diagram as follows:

$$X \overset{(Id)}\rightarrow \Delta \overset{(f_1\times f_2)}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \overset{(+\, \text{or} \,\cdot)}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \overset{(\pi = \text{Id})}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
and 
$$X\overset{(f_1+f_2 \,\text{or}\, f_1 \cdot f_2)} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal of $X^2$.

The first function is a composition of continuous functions (either inclusion or sum/multiplication within the reals). By the characteristic property, the component function below must also be continuous.

Is this proof correct and is there a better one?

Comment: You don't need the last $\pi = \operatorname{Id}$, and instead of mapping to the diagonal $\Delta$ to use $f_1\times f_2$, you could directly use $(f_1,f_2)\colon X \to \mathbb{R}^2$. And of course you must show or cite a proposition that addition and multiplication are continuous $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space of functions is defined as:
$$\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})=\prod_{x\in X}\mathbb{R}$$
and its cartesian product is identifyable by*:
$$\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})=\prod_{x\in X}\mathbb{R}^2$$
So pointwise addition is continuous:
$$\oplus:\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})\to\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R}):(f\oplus g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)$$
The proof exploits the diagram:
[image: Pointwise Operations]

*This is actually the only point one needs to prove explicitely:
$$\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})=\prod_{1,2}(\prod_{x\in X}\mathbb{R})\cong\prod_{x\in X}(\prod_{1,2}\mathbb{R})=\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R}^2)$$
Note that these spaces are really different - even from the set-theoretic point of view:
$$(i,(x,r))\in\prod_{1,2}(\prod_{x\in X}\mathbb{R}) \qquad (x,(i,r))\in\prod_{x\in X}(\prod_{1,2}\mathbb{R})$$

Comment: Could you clarify how you iterated over $X$ to make the space of functions? 
What I understand from the notation is that an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{F}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a pair $( \mathbb{R}, x)$ for $x \in X$, which doesn't define a function from $\,X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: An arbitrary element of the product $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is basically a relation $R\subseteq I\times\cup_iX_i$ with its pairs $(i,x)$ s.t. $x\in X_i$. For the special case $X_i\equiv X$ this just reduces to functions $f:I\to X$ - remember functions are nothing but special relations $(i,f(i))\in I\times X$.

Answer (score 5):

I think the key here is showing $f(x) = (f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is continuous if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are.  You'll want to invoke the characteristic property for both canonical projections:

[image]

(Note that this is analogous to Lee's proof for the product map $f_1 \times f_2$, but our $f$ is different from this product map.)  Combine this with the continuity of $x+y$ and $x\cdot y$ as maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and you'll get to your result.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this shows the pointwise sum is continuous? How does $f(x) = (f_1(x),f_2(x))$ imply the sum is continuous?

Comment: Continuity of $f_1$ and $f_2$ implies continuity of $f(x) = (f_1(x),f_2(x))$ by the characteristic property.  The sum function $s(x,y) = x + y$ is continuous because the pre-image of an open set is open (around any point $(x_0,y_0)$ there is an open ball where $|s(x,y) - s(x_0,y_0)| < \epsilon$).  Since $f$ and $s$ are continuous, so is $s \circ f$ which is the result.